While editing C++ code, using lsp, how do I display function prototypes?
I am using emacs with clangd lsp setup.
In the status bar, function prototypes are displayed as I enter code, which is very convenient.
However, sometimes there are different versions of a function taking different argument types. Then, only the first prototype is shown in the status bar, like this:
1/3 Foo(argument)

Unfortunately, I have not figured out yet how to display the other prototypes (e.g. cycle through the different variants).
Also, I have not figured out yet whether it is possibly to re-display the prototype once it has disappeared (i.e. have the prototype shown again when the cursor is on the call of that function).

If I remember correctly you can type M-n and M-p to cycle through the different prototypes while they are displayed.

In my environment (lsp + ccls) with
(setq lsp-ui-peek-enable t)

in the config the prototype is always displayed in the status line when the cursor is on a function.

Are you sure settings this variable has any influence? It does not exist in the entire lsp-mode repo.

It works at least in my setup. Regarding code: see lsp-ui-peek.el line 50.

So it's not lsp but lsp-ui. This is a different package (even if it depends on lsp). This is a very important note that should be mentioned in the answer, otherwise it won't work.

You can configure lsp to display those items separately, by using this setting in lsp-mode:
  (setq lsp-clients-clangd-args '("--background-index" "--completion-style=detailed"))

The first parameter is useful to make indexing on hard disk, the second one is what you need, and can be find out again as requested.
